# DynamoDB List search

Tags: elasticsearch, math, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I need to search the languages a student knows. I am using DynamoDb. DynamoDb doesn't have an array search. I decided to use a string with languages.
For example, if a student knows English (EN) and Spanish (ES), I will put "ENES". This did not help to search users who know only ES. Because, DynamoDb doesn't have a regex search.
One solution I see is to convert the languages to numeric values:
EN - 1, ES - 10

If a student knows "EN,ES" - 11. If a student knows "ES" - 1, "EN' - 10
Searches like, find a student who knows EN (1) is equal to searching greater or equal to 1. This includes "EN,ES" (11), "EN" (1).

The problem arises when student knows ES(10), it is automatically greater than 1 and counted as a student knows EN, because ES and EN are greater or equal to 1.

Another thought is to add language count at the beginning of the numbers:
If a student knows "EN,ES" then the input to the database is "211", 2 stands for two languages.

The questions is how to search through numbers that will include the languages queried.

Comment: As you're finding, DynamoDB is not a great search tool.  Can you elaborate on your access pattern?  Do you need to search for users who speak a single language, a list of languages, a combination of both?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan My access patters:
- Show me a users who speak "English"
- Show me users who speaks "English" and "Spanish"
A student might know unlimited number languages. Any combination might be asked work. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, DynamoDB has limited search capabilities, especially if you've got access patterns that require supporting ad-hoc queries. If the number of languages is unbounded and you need to find users who speak any combination of languages, DDB is not the best choice.  You could do this with a scan operation, but that's going down a n expensive/inefficient path.  This is an access patterns better suited for another type of database

Comment: Could you put the studentID as the PK and for each language they know, have a separate item with the SK being "Language::English. Preferably write shard that language because of what we will do next. Then have an inverted index. So the PK is the SK and the SK is the PK. Then you can get all the student's languages and all the students who know that language from the GSI.